# save output of command prompt in a text file using batch program

Tags: batch-file, jar, command-prompt

I want to save the output of command prompt in to .txt file using Batch program(.bat).I have written below batch program,it is creating new .txt file but output is not displayed in the text file.

```
@ECHO OFF
start java -jar Myjarfile.jar >> Output.txt
```

Comment: ahem - `<<` is for INput. You want OUTput, so you should use `>>`.

Comment: Your redirection (once you correct it to the right direction) is redirecting the output of the `start` command (which is empty). `start cmd /c "java -jar Myjarfile.jar >output.txt"` should help.

Comment: `<<` is an invalid redirection operator: `<` is input, `>` is output (overwrite) and `>>` is output (append)...